# How to find if a the sending message by a telegram bot has been sent to the channel correctly in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram-bot

I have designed a telegram bot (c# winforms project) which sends messages to a telegram channel. I want to find if my sending message in the last try has been sent to the channel correctly or not? Is there a way to find that?

I am using the following code in order to send my message:

```
string chatId = "@MyChannel";
string testMessage = "Hello Channel";
bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, testMessage, ParseMode.Html);
```

Comment: `var result = await SendTextMessageAsync()` 
Check result to get information about the message.

Comment: Where and how should I use this?

Comment: put the result of `bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, testMessage, ParseMode.Html);` in `result` variable. Then log result to see information about message. Result should have [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#message) structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by defining message, because `SendTextMessageAsync` method returns message on success (see [Telegram API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)), do like this:

```
Message msg = await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, testMessage, ParseMode.Html);

if (msg is null)
{
    // Message didn't arrive!
}
else
{
    // Message Arrived successfully!
}
```